# Clear mongodb using spring-mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

As so many people before me on stackoverflow I want to do junit-tests for my mongodb application. For this I let an instance run, so my tests can connect. But I want to ensure that the database is in an empty state when starting to test.

Since I'm using spring-mongodb, spring-test and all the funny spring-things I hoped to find a configuration that does this for me, until now successless.

Can anybody give me a hint how to implement this in a clean way. My idea is a InitializingBean that does this for me. But I'm not really happy with ths solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: For PHPUnit what I do is create a new database called `PHPUnit_tests` and then I drop it each test, Java should have a similar function within the database class that represents a MongoDB database.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
@Autowired
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

.....
mongoTemplate.getDb().dropDatabase();
```

Comment: New version has it as mongoTemplate.getDb().drop();

Answer (score 6):

`mongoTemplate.getDb().dropDatabase();`
can help if you will not use indexes.

In case of using indexes through spring-data-mongodb, for example `@Index` annotation, `dropDatabase()` will drop indexes as well.

My solution is cleaning up documents:

```
private void cleanUp() {
        for (String collectionName : mongoTemplate.getCollectionNames()) {
            if (!collectionName.startsWith("system.")) {
                mongoTemplate.getCollection(collectionName).remove(new BasicDBObject());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, i forget about indexes and spent a hour to find out why duplicate exception disappeared after i added database dropping code in @AfterEach.

Answer (score 2):

this is the non-deprecated answer:
`mongoTemplate.getDb().drop();`

Answer (score 1):

first

```
private @Autowired Mongo mongo;
private @Autowired MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory;
```

then

```
mongo.dropDatabase(mongoDbFactory.getDb().getName());
```